# Certificate chain not recognised by windows

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, ca

I created a self sign root CA certificate with OpenSSL (let's call it `RootCA`).
I then created an intermediate CA (let's call it `InterCA`) by signing a CSR with `RootCA`.
I finally created an enduser certificate (`EndCert.cer`) by signing a CSR with `InterCA`.

I imported the public certificate of `RootCA` (`rootca.cer`, in PEM format) into Windows trusted root certificates.
Now when I double click on `InterCA.cer`, Windows opens it, displays its certification path (child of trusted `RootCA`) and aknowledges it as a "valid certificate" (left part of the capture)
Nice. Everything perfectly as expected.

Then I made a bundle `EndCertBundle.cer` as a concatenation of `EndCert.cer` then `InterCA.cer`.
When double-clicking on this bundle, I naively expected Windows to:
. find out the certification path: `EndCert` (bundled) < `InterCA.cer` (bundled) < `RootCA` (trusted)
. aknowledge `EndCertBundle.cer` as a "valid certificate".
[Edit] ***But*** as shown in right part of the capture, Windows doesn't recognise the certification path: no parent certificate (embedded `InterCA.cer`) in the "path" box, and message "Could not find certificate issuer" in the "status" box [/Edit]

Doesn'it work like this?
What are bundles meant to, if they don't allow a certificate chain to be trusted, when the root cert is trusted, and the intermediate cert is bundled within the final cert?

[Edit] I tried importing the root certificate into Adobe Acrobat Reader.
There, the pdf's signed with `EndCert.cer` were recognised as validly signed (without importing `InterCA.cer`, neither importing `EndCert.cer`, neither signing with a bundle, just signing with `EndCert.cer`)

[image: Screen capture]

Comment: It's not clear to me what isn't working.

Comment: @President Sorry, I added an edit translating the capture. Is it clearer?

Comment: (0) not programming or development (1) issuing a cert is NOT 'signing a CSR' even though lots of people make this mistake (sadly including OpenSSL doc) (2) there are _several_ formats used for cert chains or bundles and different programs may support none, one, or several of these formats; **cryptext.dll supports only _one_ cert per .cer/.crt format file**, while for .p7b/r/s format files it launches certmgr.msc  (in MMC) which handles multiple certs but not as a chain (3) what Adobe does I can't speak to, I stopped using it years ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you double-click the file Windows only processes the first PEM object inside it.  (Supporting multiple objects out of a concatenated PEM file is really one of those "application-dependent" things).

So Windows sees only your end-entity certificate.  Your intermediate certificate is not already known to Windows (it hasn't been implicitly or explicitly saved into the user or computer CertificateAuthorities cert store), and your certificate either doesn't contain an Authority Information Access extension identifying how to go find out who the issuing CA is, or that URL wasn't resolvable.  So now it's left with "I see a cert, but can't find its parent", and shuts down.

If you had an appropriate AIA extension, or explicitly saved your issuer cert into the CertificateAuthorities store, then double-clicking would work.

Comment: So chaining certificates (like for webservers) is not applicable for windows, is this, in short version, what I should understand here?

Comment: @fpierrat It's not applicable for Windows CertUI.  Other things on Windows might support it fine.